# meteor stylus preprocessor adding `j-` prepend to every text-laign:center

Tags: javascript, css, meteor, stylus

I am using the official meteor stylus package, I am having trouble with some of the outputted css I used to be using the `mquandalle:stylus` package it stopped working after upgrading meteor, so I switched to the official stylus package. Now any time I have a `text-align:center` in a `.styl` file it outputs in css as `text-align:j-center` which obviously does not work. I don't know what else to include so please let me know what else I can include.

Here is a example section of the `.styl` code

```
.hero_d, .hero_d_b
  h1
    font-size 36px
    font-weight 400
    color #3e97b7
    padding 25px 0 15px 0
    text-align center
```

This is a list of my packages

```
# Meteor packages used by this project, one per line.
# Check this file (and the other files in this directory) into your repository.
#
# 'meteor add' and 'meteor remove' will edit this file for you,
# but you can also edit it by hand.

meteor-base@1.4.0             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mobile-experience@1.0.5       # Packages for a great mobile UX
mongo@1.5.0                   # The database Meteor supports right now
blaze-html-templates    # Compile .html files into Meteor Blaze views
session@1.1.7                 # Client-side reactive dictionary for your app
jquery                  # Helpful client-side library
tracker@1.2.0                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library

standard-minifiers@1.1.0      # JS/CSS minifiers run for production mode
es5-shim@4.8.0                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers.
ecmascript@0.11.1              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code

autopublish@1.0.7             # Publish all data to the clients (for prototyping)
insecure@1.0.7                # Allow all DB writes from clients (for prototyping)
iron:router
sewdn:masked-input
themeteorchef:jquery-validation
email@1.2.3
johannesma:meteor-flexslider
slam310:smooth-scroll
underscore
stylus
mquandalle:jeet
pward123:rupture
```

Replaced `stylus,mqandalle:jeet&pward123:rupture` with `coagmano:stylus`

I have a `imports.styl` file the is imported into my `layout.styl` file and I get the following error

```
Cannot read file {}/C:/Users/Anders/AppData/Local/.meteor/packages/coagmano_stylus/1.0.3/plugin.compileStylusBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileStylusBatch/node_modules/jeet/jeet.styl for
   /client/application/styles/imports.styl

   client/application/styles/layout.styl: Stylus compiler error: client/application/styles/imports.styl:1:9
   1| @import 'jeet'
   --------------^
   2| @import 'rupture'
   3| rupture.scale = 0 320px 525px 600px 700px 850px 1048px 1300px
   4|
```

This is the `imports.styl` file

```
@import 'jeet'
@import 'rupture'
rupture.scale = 0 320px 525px 600px 700px 850px 1048px 1300px
```

Comment: Is it possible you have created a variable or mixin called `center`?
If you do a find-all for `j-center`, what can you find?

Comment: @FredStark when I do a find-all for `j-center` nothing shows up in any of my `.styl` files or anywhere.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is I am using a package called http://jeet.gs/ and there is a style where you can center things but the entire declaration is `center(1024px)` for example and I never had this issue before.

Comment: Try removing `stylus`, `mquandalle:jeet` and `pward123:rupture` and install `coagmano:stylus` instead. I'm the maintainer of that fork and it comes with jeet and rupture

Comment: @fredstark ok I tried that, I get a new error now, I added it above with a explanation.

Comment: Ahh right, jeet is implicitly included so you don't need to `@import` it. It should just be available already

Comment: I'm surprised importing it throws an error though. Might be an interaction with Meteor's import resolver

Comment: @fredstark any ideas of what I could try?

Comment: remove both `@import lines` for jeet and rupture. Their mixins will be available without importing

Comment: perfect that worked, if you want to write an answer about changing the packages and removing the imports I will select it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really certain of the cause of the problem, but it can be solved by removing your current stylus packages:

```
stylus
mquandalle:jeet
pward123:rupture
```

and replacing them with `coagmano:stylus` (Disclaimer, I'm the maintainer of that fork)

```
meteor add coagmano:stylus
```

That package comes with `jeet`, `rupture`, `nib` and others bundled and set to automatically load into global scope.

This means that you don't need to import them, and in fact doing so will throw errors because of how it conflicts with Meteor's import syntax.

To remove those errors, find and remove any import statements for stylus libraries like these:

```
@import 'jeet'
@import 'rupture'
```